# Softwares to run old version of windows application/games on lastest version of windows 10

Tags: windows

Is there is any wine like software/emulator for windows to run windows XP or prior version of windows such as windows 95 application on latest version of windows 10?

Comment: You will probably have to use a virtual machine and an original OS image and license.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You can download the [Windows Virtual PC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702) directly from Microsoft.

You can download [Windows XP Mode](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002) directly from Microsoft. I don't believe that this actually has an expiration date.

You can also download [Windows 7-10 virtual machines](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) directly from Microsoft.

These machines are ostensibly provided to let you test browsers, but you can install other software on them. Read the procedure to snapshot them so that after they expire in 90 days.

Comment: Thanks for responding, the virtual machine required separate resources as hard-disk , memory etc which I am is not willing to install is there is any other better workaround?

Comment: It'll all run on your machine as is. The allocations are from existing resources. The memory is only allocated during use. The drive space allocation, however, is real and since you might only be installing a game or two, they will only need enough space to satisfy the game's requirements. Maybe a GB or two?